# How to prove that for all natural $n$, $133|11^{n+2}+12^{2n+1}$

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility

> How to prove that for every natural $n$, the number 
>   $$11^{n+2} +12^{2n+1}$$
>   is divisible by $133$?

I tried Induction method, so assuming that
$$
n=k \implies
A = (11^{k+2} +12^{2k+1} ) \pmod{133} \equiv 0
$$
Then trying to prove that
$$
n=k+1 \implies
B = (11^{k+3} +12^{2k+3} ) \pmod{133} \equiv 0
$$
For this I wanted to split $B$ into multiplication with at least one multiple of $A$.  But no luck.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that $11^{k+2}+12^{2k+1}=133\lambda$, you can infer that $11^{k+2}=133\lambda-12^{2k+1}$.

Thus you have that $$11^{k+3}+12^{2k+3}= 11^{k+2}\cdot 11 +144 \cdot 12^{2k+1}=11\cdot 133\lambda -11\cdot 12^{2k+1} +144 \cdot 12^{2k+1} =11\cdot 133\lambda +12^{2k+1} \cdot (144-11)=11\cdot 133\lambda +133\cdot 12^{k+1} $$
 which is divisible by 133

Comment: Exactly what I've been failing to get. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$11,144$ are roots of the quadratic $$(n-11)(n-144)=n^2-155n+1584$$

Therefore your sequence $$a_n=121\times 11^n+12\times 144^n$$ satisfies the recursion $$a_{n+1}=155a_{n+1}-1584a_n$$

The initial values are $$a_0=133\quad a_1=3059$$ and both of these are divisible by $133$ so we are done.

Note:  It wasn't necessary to exhibit the linear recursion as it was clear that there was one like that and that's all we needed.

Comment: I like this method, because it unlocks the mystery behind the persistence of divisibility which forms the basis of so many similar questions.

Comment: It's simply and awesome. Just wow . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just calculate mod $133$:

$$11^{n+2}+12^{2n+1} = 121\cdot 11^n +12\cdot 144^n $$ $$\equiv  121\cdot 11^n + 12\cdot 11^n \equiv 133\cdot 11^n \equiv 0 \pmod{133}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle 11^{k + 3} + 12^{2k + 3} = 11 \times 11^{k + 2} +
\underbrace{\qquad 144\qquad}_{\displaystyle =\ 133 + 11} \times 12^{2k + 1} =
11\left(\color{red}{11^{k + 2} + 12^{2k + 1}}\right) + \color{red}{133} \times 12^{2k + 1}$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that $133 = 7 \times 19$ and both $7$ and $19$ are prime. Also recall that if $p,q$ are prime, and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $p|n$ and $q|n$ then $pq|n$.